# Can I create a C# Web.Api method that accepts a parameter AND JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I would like to pass some JSON data into my controller, but also a string to identify type. I'm wondering if I can create something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Write(string documentType, string jsonData)
{
    ...
```

I have a method like that, but when I try from another app to do this:

```
// packageObject is an instance of my object I want JSON serialized
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("EdiDocument/Write?documentType=211", packageObject);
```

I get:

> StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'

Is this something I can do?

Comment: Can't you wrap the packageObject together with the documentType into a new object?

Comment: The POST message body for web API acccepts a single parameter, you need to create a new type that contains both of those parameters. Alternatively let the Web API delegate to the JSON parser automatically, why try to pass json when it could be deserialized for you in an expected type?

Comment: I'm trying to have one endpoint handle multiple incoming types.

Comment: If you want to use a querystring parameter then it wouldn't be in the method signature, you would have to get it directly from the Request object.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way, you have an endpoint address (e.g. http://yourserver/yourapp/yourcontroller/) and a payload (in your case the payload is json).  If you want to pass information it has to fit into one of those things...  You could accomplish what you want by (1) using an additional parameter in the endpoint address, or just (2) adding the new value as a property in your json payload.

for option 1 you could use something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{docType}"]
public void Write(string docType, string jsonData) {....}
```

This would mean your endpoing would change to something like:

```
http://yourserver/yourapp/yourcontroller/docTypeGoesHere
```

Option 2 is to just expand your json object to include this other bit of info.  In other words, add a 'documentType' property to your jsonData object.

I'm guessing you're trying NOT to modify the json object's structure, which leaves you with option 1.